# Why does the hlookup function return 0?

Tags: excel-formula

[image]Why does this hlookup function return 0?

A1 = 2, B1 = 0, C1 = 0

```
=hlookup(3,A1:C1,1,true)
```

Reading the description here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f, it says for the range parameter (the last parameter):

"If TRUE or omitted, an approximate match is returned. In other words, if an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned"

The next largest value is 2 (in A1) which is less than the lookup value (3).

Using MS Office 365 Apps for enterprise

Comment: Upload a picture.

Comment: The issue that you miss is that when using `TRUE` the values must be sorted ascending:`If range_lookup is TRUE, the values in the first row of table_array must be placed in ascending order` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f#:~:text=If%20range_lookup%20is%20TRUE%2C%20the%20values%20in%20the%20first%20row%20of%20table_array%20must%20be%20placed%20in%20ascending%20order

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.  How to return 2 with an unsorted list?  The highest number less than or equal to the lookup value.

Comment: Use XLOOKUP if you have it.  Then the sorting does not matter. Or if numbers then `MAXIFS()` will also do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HLOOKUP will require that the values be sorted when using TRUE:

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f#:~:text=If%20range_lookup%20is%20TRUE%2C%20the%20values%20in%20the%20first%20row%20of%20table_array%20must%20be%20placed%20in%20ascending%20order](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f#:%7E:text=If%20range_lookup%20is%20TRUE%2C%20the%20values%20in%20the%20first%20row%20of%20table_array%20must%20be%20placed%20in%20ascending%20order)

But we can use MAXIFS if they are numbers:

```
=MAXIFS(A1:C1,A1:C1,"<="&3)
```

OR XLOOKUP which does not care if sorted or not.

```
=XLOOKUP(3,A1:C1,A1:C1,"",-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Adding for completeness to eliminate redundancy:  =let(r,A1:C1,xlookup(3,r,r,"",-1))   Then the range only needs to be listed once.

Answer (score 0):

The `HLOOKUP` function returns `0` because the value `3` is not found in the lookup range `A1:A3`. The `HLOOKUP` function performs a horizontal search, i.e., it searches for the lookup value vertically in the first row of the lookup range.

Since the lookup value `3` is not found in the range `A1:A3`, which only contains the values `2`, `0`, and `0`, the `HLOOKUP` function returns the value specified in the `result_vector` argument, which in this case is `1`. When the value is not found and the `range_lookup` argument is set to `True` (which it is in this case), the `HLOOKUP` function returns the closest match that is less than the lookup value. In this case, since there is no match, it returns `0`.